# RaspberryPi MonoDevelop C# - Error: The type of namespace name 'Serialization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml'

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, raspberry-pi

Need help to solve an error. I have created a ChatBot in 'Visual Studios 2012' and it runs with no problem. However when I move it over to the RaspberryPi to edit it in MonoDevelop I have the following Error:

> "The type of namespace name 'Serialization' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Xml'".

This is  on the  `using system.Xml.Serialization`.

I also get the error:

> "The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializer' could not be found. Are
>   you missing an assembly reference?".

This is on the following two lines:

`XmlSerializer responseSave;
XmlSerializer allSave;`

I believe that this is due to the initial error of the namespace and will automatically solve once the first error is solved.

The catch: When I type `using System.Xml.Serialization` it auto-completes.
When I highlight `XmlSerializer` with the cursor I get the following:

> Class
>   class System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer 
>   Class for serializing and and deserializing objects to XML.
>   (Yes it says and twice!) This indicates it knows what this class is... So why the errors?

I am using the following:

```
using System
using System.Collections.Generic
using System.Linq
using System.Text
using System.Xml
using System.IO
using System.Xml.Serialization
```

And in my references I have the following:

> System System.Core 
>   System.Xml.Linq
>   System.Data.DataSetExtensions
>   Microsoft.CSharp
>   System.Data
>   System.Xml
>   MonoDevelop.Core
>   MonoDevelop.XmlEditor
>   System.Runtime.Serialization

Extra Notes: 
I also get 3 warnings:

> The reference 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[bunch of letters and numbers]' is not valid for the target framework of the project. ([Project Name])
>
> The reference 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[bunch of letters and numbers]' is not valid for the target framework of the project. ([Project Name])
>
> The reference 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[Bunch of letters and numbers]' is not valid for the target framework of the project. ([Project Name])

Comment: I'd suggest removing and then re-adding those references. While Mono does not implement all of .NET currently, I would assume those at least must exist... but you should check Mono's official site.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error while compiling on linux and in my case it was due to a case sensitivity issue in the reference name.

When looking at the reference properties for the System.Xml reference in Visual Studio I noticed that the name was shown as System.XML. Other projects in the solution that referenced the same assembly showed the name as System.Xml as expected. Removing and re-adding the reference didn't have any effect for some reason.

I ended up manually editing the .csproj file for the problematic project to correct the case accordingly:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```